# Added "\n" by using the split function in the method but is not working while running the Script. Can I get some inputs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

/* This is my Method */

```java
    public static void inputvalues(WebDriver driver,Map<String, String> formEntryMap,String col) 
    {
        if(formEntryMap.containsKey(columnKey))
        {   
            String [] inputInfo = formEntryMap.get(colKey).trim().split("\n");
            
            for(String inputItem:inputInfo)
            {
                String xPath = XpathofInputfield
                inputEntry(driver, xPath,inputItem);
        
            }
        }
    }
```

Feature File is defined as below:

```
| Column | Value         |
                                                                       
| Status | 542567 785454 |
```

Now When I Run the above file it should add the values one below the other in the status text box.
So while adding it should be like: 542567
785454
But the issue is it is not adding the value like that and is just adding as per what is given in the `Feature File`.
My requirement: It should split and add the value in the Newline by reading from the method.

I would need a solution for this. Can someone please give your inputs.

Comment: Can you add a sysout statement after your split() to see the output? Also, dont you need to split by blankspace to see the value in next line?

Comment: Get the inputItem:[Ljava.lang.String;@5a0b550a
getting this after adding sysout

Comment: but when i do a sysout after enterng the for loop it takes the value as given in the feature file .Can you please give inputs on where it is going wrong

Comment: Also, dont you need to split by blankspace to see the value in next line?  - so should this be split("\n","")

Comment: What your input value look like?

Comment: 5323146 should be in the first line                                                                                                                     5212435 should be in the second line of the input text box

Comment: and could add more values as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works: Change your split() to

```
String [] inputInfo = formEntryMap.get(colKey).trim().split("\\W+");
```

Updated Code:
Your inputEntry() should have something like this:-

```
xpath.sendKeys(inputItem,"\n");
```

Comment: it takes only the 2nd value and ignores the first value

Comment: Any other inputs pls

Comment: if you iterate through the inputInfo and do sysout, what do you see?

Comment: Get inputinfo:[Ljava.lang.String;@18c95fbb
Get inputinfo:[Ljava.lang.String;@18c95fbb

Comment: after for loop sysout and i shows both the values

Comment: but while adding to the text box it adds only the second value

Comment: you mean here inputEntry(driver, xPath,inputItem);? please do a sysout right at the beginning of the method to see what values gets into this.

Comment: while printing it prints both the values but while adding the text to the text box it takes the second value only is there something else i need to do?

Comment: for(String inputItem:inputInfo)
   {
   System.out.println("Get the item:"+inputItem);

Comment: after you split, its 2 different values and for each value you are running the inputEntry(). So what you are seeing is right.

Comment: String [] inputInfo = formEntryMap.get(colum/nKey).trim().split("\\W+");
   
   
     System.out.println("Get inputinfo:"+inputInfo);

Comment: ok but why is that i is not keying the first value? it ignores and enters only the second value and stuck still

Comment: a solution would be helpful

Comment: do you have a clear statement in your inputEntry()?

Comment: |  Label    |       Value                |
                                                                                                                                                                                          
     | Status   | 5635997  50496300 |

Comment: This is my input entry in the feature file

Comment: Sorry misread yes it does have clear statement in the input entry

Comment: So if you comment out the clear statement, its going to retain both the values.

Comment: i removed the clear statement but now when i run it enters both the values without any space - 563599750496300

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Its a Status text box where i have to input the values one below the other and should not be in the same line i.e. every input value entered should be in a new line

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: it cannot be accessed outside

Comment: any other inputs

Comment: is it one single input textbox that you need to input one below the other? If so, can you add "\n" to the sendkeys()?

Comment: will add the script

Comment: WebElement Xpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));

   Xpath.sendKeys(formEntryMap.get(columnKey));
   Xpath.sendKeys("\n");

Comment: tried it this wayand is not working is there something wrong with this piece of code

Comment: if you are sending formEntryMap.get(columnKey) then why are you splitting the inputvalues?

Comment: bz formentryMap has the value and need to split those values pls let me know where iam gong wrong to get a solution

Comment: for the above where i have used Xpath.sendkeys i have not used split function

Comment: have used Split only for the first script which i shared.hope iam clear

Comment: What was your initial ask of this question?

Comment: ok first was i used the split function to split the values with "\n"  and had shared the first script saying that it is not splitting . Second i had just shared another script where i took the just used the Xpath and passed the values and using sendkeys had used "\n" for entering the value in new line

Comment: so my initial question was when i used the split function it is not working and you had given me a workaround where on entering split("\\W+") it is adding both the values without any space

Comment: Then you had asked me to just try using "\n" by using sendKeys and tried with that as well in this case did not use the split   and this also did not work

Comment: Please accept the answer if i answered your initial ask. So to add both the values i have updated the code. Please try that

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but one question what does split("\\W+") do?

Comment: \\W+ means not a alphanumeric character